# moving average within a resampled set

Tags: moving-average, resampling

I have a dataframe, df, of a multiple-year hourly dataset and want to **calculate 8-hour moving average *within* each day**. Thank you to PatrickT for helpful discussion, I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

numbers = [random.randint(10, 80) for i in range(48)]
datetimes = pd.date_range(start="2021-08-01 00:00:00", end="2021-08-2 23:00:00", freq='1h')
df = pd.DataFrame (data = numbers, index = datetimes, columns = ['var'])
df.resample('D')['var'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(8).mean())
```

And it worked!

My initial problem was I used "df.resample('D')['var'].rolling(8).mean()", which gave me an error of " index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2". Inspired by discussion with PatrickT combined with internet search, I used apply() and it worked! Though I still don't know why resample() cannot be followed by rolling().

Comment: Thank you PatrickT for the suggestion. I added  a sample code to reproduce the error message.

Comment: Do you need to aggregate after you resample and before you roll? e.g. `df.resample('D')['var'].sum()` or `df.resample('D')['var'].max()`?

Comment: I don't need to aggregate after I resample and before I use rolling. I have a hourly dataset. I would like to calculate 8-hour moving average of a variable for each day and then get a daily maximum of the 8-hour average data. That's why I used resample('D') followed by rolling.  Perhaps "resample" is not the right function to use in this case as I got the error shown above. But then how to use rolling just for the hourly data within each day? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you mean adding .first() right after resample, i.e. df.resample('D')['var'].first('1D').rolling(8).mean()? The error went away but the results are incorrect, I got "2021-08-01   NaN
2021-08-02   NaN
Freq: D, Name: var, dtype: float64". I probably didn't understand what you meant correctly...

Comment: That's what I meant. When you resample with `.first()`, if I understand correctly, it keeps the first data point used for the resampled data. You can choose `.last()` or `.mean()`, etc. Maybe edit your question with the results and describe what you expected to find instead.

Comment: I edited my question with the results and further explained what I aimed to do. Many thanks!

Comment: That's what I can't be sure of. How do I check that? I meant it to be 8 hour, because I have an hourly dataset. In using resample('D'), I hoped to roll the 24 hourly values within each day over an 8-hour window...

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert and will defer to anyone with a better answer. It seems that `.pad()` helps:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

datetimes = pd.date_range(start="2019-08-01 00:00:00", end="2021-08-2 23:00:00", freq='1h')
numbers = [random.randint(10, 80) for i in range(len(datetimes))]
df = pd.DataFrame ({'data': numbers, 'index': datetimes})
df.head()

df.set_index('index').resample('D').pad().rolling(window=8).mean()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for having spent time helping out! It seems we're getting closer by using pad(), though it is not exactly what I aimed for. I wanted to get 8-hour moving average over the 24 hourly numbers within each day. Hence, after applying rolling(8), the last 7 number at hours 17:00 - 23:00 each day should be NaN. Nonetheless your help's greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you cannot find exactly what you're looking for by searching the manual for keywords like `pad()`, simply ask another question. Remember to show your fake data and the **expected output**. I'm sure a knowledgeable person will answer this time. The best questions are precise. If you find the trick by yourself, you can edit my answer with the added information and explanation below it (I'll be asked to review the edits, I think). All the best!

Comment: You can also clean up your question above to make it easier to understand what you are asking, for future readers of the thread. Sometimes questions like yours receive a valuable answer months after they are asked!  You can also clean up the comments section by keeping only the comments that are of value now.